# Hash Table searching for spell checker in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code which tries to spell check words using a hash table algorithm . It compares the file to be spell checked to a file which is a dictionary and returns all misspelled words. I have successfully carries out this task with a binary and linear search but am finding this more challenging.

The dictionary used is 1 word per line and the testfile is lots of text

```
import re


dictionary = {}
document = []
with open('dict.txt') as f:
for word in f:
    dictionary[word] = 1


with open("testfile.txt" , encoding="utf8") as f:
    content = f.read().split(" ")
    content = [item.lower() for item in content]
    content = ' '.join(content)
    content = re.findall("[a-z]+", content)
    for line in content:
           document.append(line)



for line in document:
    for word in line:
        if word not in dictionary:
            print("{} on line #{} is spelled wrong!".format(word, document.index(line)))
```

the code is giving an output of:

`t on line #0 is spelled wrong!
h on line #0 is spelled wrong!
e on line #0 is spelled wrong!
c on line #1 is spelled wrong!
o on line #1 is spelled wrong!
m on line #1 is spelled wrong!
p on line #1 is spelled wrong!
l on line #1 is spelled wrong!
e on line #1 is spelled wrong!
t on line #1 is spelled wrong!`

which is spelling out the test file letter by letter as you can see it says "the complete". It seems to be treating each letter in the testfile as a word which is not correct.

Comment: What is the question? Do you want us to review the code? If yes, then you should ask this question on Code review

Comment: No the code isnt working correctly. Ill update the post.

Comment: I think you want `for word in line.split():` so that you are iterating through the list of words in line and not the characters in line

Comment: You need to use the `split() `method to split the line.. otherwise it will split hte string.. `for word in line.split():`

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problem:

```
for word in line:
```

Iterating over a string yields its characters, not its words. Using the variable name `word` does not change that, since Python does not look at variable names to figure out what you want. `word` is still going to be a single character.

You want something more like:

```
for word in line.split():
```

... though this will include punctuation that abuts words. Really, you probably want a regular expression that matches one or more word characters in a row:

```
import re

# same as before, up to:
for word in re.findall(r"\w+", line):
```